# Changing img src in angular 6 not displaying new image until it's been fully loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I'm having some unexpected behavior with my angular app when I update an image's source and I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I have something like this:

```
<img [src]="imageUrl" />
```

and update imageUrl in my component whenever users click a button to see the next image. This works.

When the first image loads I see it loading from top to bottom.

However, subsequent images don't display this way. When I change the imageUrl variable, I can see the url change in another place on the screen, but the actual image does not change until it's fully loaded, and then it pops in to place.

**So my question:** Is there some way to make the subsequent images load in the same manner as the original? Some of my images can be quite large, and are useful to users before they're 100% loaded, so I'd really like for them to be able to see them as they load if possible.

I tried using document.getElementById and then updating the src attribute that way, and it seemed to perform the same way unfortunately. If I do something like this:

```
const container = document.getElementById('imagePlaceholder');
const img = document.createElement('img');
container.innerHTML = '';
img.setAttribute('src', this.imageUrl);
container.appendChild(img);
```

It does load the way I'd like.

Any ideas?

**edit:** Found some good example images for what I'm talking about from [here](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-asynchronously-loading-image). First image loads [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FFMk.gif), and then the subsequent images load [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhEUN.gif) (without the loading indicator)

**edit 2:** Figured out a better workaround. Using *ngFor and putting imageUrl as the only thing in it gets the desired results. Still weird, but much better than fiddling with the dom.

```
imageUrls = [ this.imageUrl ];
...
<img *ngFor="let url of imageUrls" [src]="url" />
```

Comment: save your images as "interlaced" or "progressive" depending on the type. That should do it.

Comment: You might preload the images, so you'd not load them on click.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - Just tried this, but it didn't seem to change anything. I still see the first image load top to bottom, and all subsequent images just pop in to place eventually.

Comment: @KoshVery - I do preload the next image, which definitely helps, but sometimes people need to skip over multiple images. There are a lot of images, so preloading all of them is not an option.

Comment: Where do you get images from? third source?

Comment: @MaihanNijat - they're from a variety of places, and all seem to be behaving the same as far as I've seen. The ones I'm using for testing I took myself. They're all jpgs, which have been re-saved with photoshop. Per Randy's suggestion I also re-re-saved them with the progressive format option.

Comment: @Ingsht https://next.plnkr.co/edit/5kD5lriM7o8WN5mX?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1

Comment: @MaihanNijat - I think this is doing it the same way I'm currently doing it. I tried changing the urls to larger images and slowing down my network with the chrome dev tools, and I get the same issue. First one loads top to bottom, second image just pops in to place after it loads.

Comment: I think, If you are not preloading, then this happens with all applications or any method you use.

Comment: @Ingsht. I had this issue on my app and I could not figure it out either for a long time specially when your trying to display multiple components all at once. My app is a large scale app. I have a carousel on top and categories at the bottom.   If they are not in cached, the categories would display first before the carousel. My solution is this: I kept the height fix( this.height = window.innerHeight * .5) and at least you won't see the image loading from top to bottom. See my app at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5lHNx640wY. Hope you find your answers and happy coding.